# How can I append user inputs in a single array on localStorage key in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

Every time a new input is entered, I am trying to make it so that input is appended into an array in localstorage. I am currently using
`localStorage.setItem('Inputs', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("inputVal").value))` which takes the value but does not add it to any array and instead replaces the previous value. How would I go abouts adding the input into an array for localstorage? I am also wondering if I could use `.appendChild()`?

quick update:
I have also tried

```
var valueS = document.getElementById("inputVal").value;
    const arr = [];
    const newArry = [
      ...arr,
      valueS
    ]
    //arr.push(valueS)
    localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(newArry))
```

Comment: You need to load the JSON you've previously stored in local storage and assign that to your `arr` variable. Right now you just overwrite it.

Comment: `const arr = [];` should be the array from localStorage, it should only be a new array on the first time setting it

Comment: you're spreading an empty array into the newArry, how would it include the previous localStorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @nIta, @Patrick Evans and @David Grosh pointed out, the `const arr = []` should contain the localstorage array.

The solution that works for me is as follows:

```
var valueS = document.getElementById("inputVal").value;
    const arr = [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'))];
    const newArry = [
      ...arr,
      valueS
    ]
    localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(newArry))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me :

1. You have to store the input value
2. get JSON item from Localtostage or if null assign a blank array.
3. append value to an old array
4. new array Set item to JSON data.

> ```
> var value = document.getElementById("inputVal").value;
> let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) || []
> data.push(value)
> localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data))
> ```